# Comparing two separate columns on two separate sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I need to compare values on two separate sheets, both are in column H starting at 2.  One sheet is labeled final, the other data. If it is in final and not in data then highlight in final. If something found in data is not in final copy it into final (whole row) at the bottom.  It is all text.  Column H is titled "Reference".

Answer (score 0):

**code 1**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Target.Column <> 8 Then Exit Sub

    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim rng As Range, cell As Range

    lastRow = Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    If lastRow < 2 Then lastRow = 2

    Set rng = Range("H2:H" & lastRow)

    For Each cell In rng

        With Sheets("data")
            a = Application.VLookup(cell.Value, .Range("H2:H" & .Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row), 1, 0)

            If IsError(a) Then
                cell.Interior.Color = vbYellow
                Else
                cell.Interior.Color = xlNone
            End If
        End With

    Next

    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

**code 2**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Target.Column <> 8 Then Exit Sub

    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim rng As Range, cell As Range

    lastRow = Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    If lastRow < 2 Then lastRow = 2

    Set rng = Range("H2:H" & lastRow)

    For Each cell In rng

        With Sheets("final")
             a = Application.VLookup(cell.Value, .Range("H2:H" & .Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row), 1, 0)

            If IsError(a) Then
               cell.Copy .Range("H" & .Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
            End If
        End With

    Next

    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: I've entered the info as described but as i run my other macros nothing happens.  Could you comment this for me so I could continue trouble shooting this.

Comment: @user2453057 Make sure you have put the code on sheet code section as showed in the image. Also ensure `Application.EnableEvents=True` so that macro can respond to events. On any change in worksheet in column H the macro would trigger